# SDammann.WebApi.Versioning : asp.net versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/Participant/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route2",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler : new TokenValidationHandler() 
);
```

My controller is `ParticipantController`.

If I add two routes, exception is thrown from SDamman dll (object null reference error). I need two routes, to add a `MessageHandler` only for the "Route2".

Can anyone assist me in this?

I have added below lines in `global.asax.cs` file

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),
                    new RouteVersionedControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

Since I am using .Net framework version 4, I have used package id="SDammann.WebApi.Versioning" version="2.0.0.3" targetFramework="net40"

### Exception details

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> at
>   SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.VersionedControllerSelector.GetControllerNameFromRequest(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) in z:\Developing\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\src\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\VersionedControllerSelector.cs:line
>   187  at
>   SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.RouteVersionedControllerSelector.GetControllerIdentificationFromRequest(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) in z:\Developing\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\src\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\RouteVersionedControllerSelector.cs:line
>   34  at
>   SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.VersionedControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) in z:\Developing\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\src\SDammann.WebApi.Versioning\VersionedControllerSelector.cs:line
>   112  at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the issue is. I missed out to add default controller in Route1.

Working code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/Participant/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller: "Participant", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```